# Updating texture using glTexImage2D(..) in OpenglES2 [Android]

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Initialization code creates one RGB one-color texture with 128x128 pixels:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures ( 1, textureId, 0 );
GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0] );
GLES20.glTexImage2D ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0,GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer );|
GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
```

after initialization I have the proper texture and everything works ok. At some poin I have to make some changes in my texture or even replace it completelly with other image:

```
GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0] );
GLES20.glTexImage2D ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0,GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer );|
GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
```

But glTexImage2D dosen't make any changes to the texture and returns no error. But this code works correctly in my iOS project, but in case of android it doesn't. It looks like I can't use glTexImage2D(..) twice with same texture, in other words, the only way to modify my texture is to create new one and delete old one, but why it's works correctly in iOS? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `glTexImage2D` is definitely not the only way to specify a texture image. You completely forgot about the actual recommenden and more performant way, that you should always prefer: `glTexSubImage2D`. Only use `glTexImage2D` when the size or format of your texture changes, but never for just updating the image with another one of the same size. But nevertheless, `glTexImage2D` should still work, even if not the correct approach, so this is no answer but just a comment. But maybe Android takes `glTexSubImage2D`'s somehow underrated role a bit more seriously.

Comment: Yep, I know about glTexSubImage2D, but in my case I have to change even the metrics of the texture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, that was my fault. I tried to call glTexImage2D function from other thread (not from GL thread). Now everything works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I think **glTexImage2D()** is used to define a texture and **glTexSubImage2D()** is used to redefine/update a texture.

You might just have to switch to glTexSubImage2D() for your texture updating.

Comment: Although `glTexSubImage2D` is the correct approach, `glTexImage2D` should still work.

Comment: Yes, I know about glTexSubImage2D, but in this specific case I thought about changing of whole image of texture and even its metric. In my case I use it for progressive downloading of textures in 360 deg. panotrama. So my question was about glTexImage2D(), rather why it doesnt work on Android, bnut works fine in iOS. In other words, is it bug in device's ogl driver, or i just use glTexImage2D function incorrectly and it shouldn't work?